# NSuserDefaults not saving until i close the app swift

Tags: ios, xcode, swing, nsuserdefaults

same code was working properly yesterday, not sure why not working today. I'm trying to save number of levels completed by user and unlock next. heres my code

```
var defaults = NSUserDefaults()
var levelsCompleted = defaults.intergerForKey("levelsCompleted")
```

save the user completes the level

```
if levelfinished() {
defaults.setInteger(nextlevel, forKey: "levelsCompleted")
defaults.synchronize()
println("level \(levelsCompleted) unlocked)
}
```

no matter what level i complete, it always prints users last session saved levels
so if i run the first time , the value returns always 1 even when level **10th** is completed but when i close the app and rerun, then 11 levels are unlocked and it returns **11** even if i complete the 20th level. So im not sure why is it not saving properly. It was working fine yesterday, as soon as i completed any level it used to print correct nextlevel value. 
 heres the screenshot https://i.stack.imgur.com/1i0I6.png it always says **unlocked 6**

Comment: synchronize() returns a bool saying if it was successful, so you might want to check that.

Comment: not returning anything , heres the screenshot http://i.imgur.com/It8LOpX.png it always says **unlocked 6**

Comment: of course it is returning something, either a true or a false. return doesn't mean print to the console, you have to something like "let didWork = defaults.synchronize()" and then check the value of "didWork"

Comment: I am not into Swift but for me it looks like you are just setting the new value to the `NSUserDefaults` but not to your local variable `levelsCompleted`. I think your `println statement` should print `nextlevel` not `levelsCompleted`. So what i basically mean: You are setting `levelsCompleted` at the beginning from your `NSUserDefaults`, then if level is finished you set the new value to the `NSUserDefaults` but print the local variable which still has the old value from the `NSUserDefaults`.

Comment: @manecosta it is returning true

Comment: @dehlen its not about only printing , when i go back to main menu, i see that all the completed levels are still locked.

Comment: I think one could help you better with some more code/context. How do you unlock the levels ? Where exactly do you read/write to the NSUserDefaults. Provide a better overview and I am sure we can solve your problem in a second.

Comment: Also you say it works correct if you close and open the app again. Do you retrieve the stored `NSUserDefault` value in `viewDidLoad()` ? It could be possible that this is only called the first time you open the view and when you go back to the same view only `viewDidAppear()` is called. Try to change your code into this method, but again without more context it is only guessing.

Comment: @djay I just posted answer for you. Please check.

Comment: @dehlen yes ofc i retrieve the stored data but it doesn't update until i close the app and start again

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's hard to post code as a comment so lets try to work here.

Try changing your if statement to this:

```
if levelfinished() {
    defaults.setInteger(nextlevel, forKey: "levelsCompleted")
    defaults.synchronize()
    levelsCompleted = defaults.intergerForKey("levelsCompleted")
    println("level \(levelsCompleted) unlocked)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Getting the completed levels like this:

```
var levelsCompleted = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().intergerForKey("levelsCompleted")
```

Save the user complete level like this:

```
if levelfinished() 
{
    NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().setInteger(nextlevel, forKey: "levelsCompleted")
    NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().synchronize()
}
```

Let me know if you have any questions.